# Writing information on an always readable text file with Python

Tags: jquery, python, python-2.7, fopen

I've a project at which I've to plot graphs using jQuery AJAX requests, by reading a constantly updated .txt file with python. However, what I really want to do is to keep the content of the file, until the next data is overwritten to file. However, when i try to read this data stack file, -since the python script constantly overwrites it with new info- **Sadly, I'm not able to see the content everytime.**

This is what I've done so far:

```
mydatatosend = str(distance0)+","+str(time0)+","+str(distance1).....)
print mydatatosend
text_file = open("sensor_file.inc","a")
text_file.write(mydatatosend)
text_file.close()
```

For the record, I've tried FTP upload-like solution, but I've a problem with FTP Server, so it's not an option for now.
Also, any info on how to pass the parameters to a php-file can also do the trick.
I really appreciate your assistance, thanks already!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be simpler than I think. Problem is solved when I change the "a" to "w+r"

Here is the working final code:

```
mydatatosend = str(distance0)+","+str(time0)+","+str(distance1).....)
print mydatatosend
text_file = open("sensor_file.inc","w+r")
text_file.write(mydatatosend)
text_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
new_text = str(distance0)+","+str(time0)+","+str(distance1).....) 
print new_text

text_file = open("sensor_file.inc","rw")
previous_text = text_file.read()

total_text = previous_text + new_text    

text_file.write(total_text)
text_file.close()
```

This reads the data previously on the file, appends the new data to this and rewrites the data back to the file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: previous_text = text_file.read()
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

This error shows up

Comment: I dunno what the 'a' flag does. Fixed in the question now.

Answer (score 0):

The standard practice for updating a file in-place is to write a new file (with a different name), then [os.rename()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rename) the new one as the original file name.  The file system will perform an "atomic" operation so only one file is available at that name, and block all reads until the rename is complete.  Clean and fast.

```
import os
file_name = "sensor_file.inc"
new_file_name = "sensor_file.inc-new"
text_file = open(new_file_name,"w")
text_file.write(mydatatosend)
text_file.close()
os.rename(new_file_name, file_name)
```

Comment: I'm a beginner when it comes to python, your approach seemed right to me, can you please provide an example python code for me to try. Thanks